# Liberty VirtualPOT -> Websphere 9.x will be the last version of WAS Classic?

Tags: websphere-liberty

I was watching a recent VirtualPOT on Liberty and thought I heard the presenter mention that Websphere 9.x will be the last version of WAS Classic.  In other words in the relatively near future Liberty will be the only WAS option that gets new feature updates.  Did I hear the presenter correctly?  Need to know.

Comment: If you heard correctly, I personally think it was likely mis-conveyed or misinterpreted. 

It has already been formally announced that all editions of WebSphere are on a continuous delivery model which obviates the need for new major versions and releases.    Perhaps that was the context/genesis, combined with maybe some loose phrasing.

Comment: I agree with @covener.  But, just to be sure, can you provide a link to the specific VirtualPOT that you were listening to?  Just so that we can ensure the proper message is being conveyed (or not).  Thanks.

Comment: I'll need to re-listen to the presentation to see where it led me to the conclusion I reached.  Just trying to figure out whether it makes sense to expend the effort to migrate to Liberty now, or take the easier route of migrating from WAS 8.x to WAS 9.x and then revisiting Liberty in the future. I'm sure IBM will continue to provide support for running older applications.  Guess we'll find out in the future whether IBM ever releases a WAS 10.x, or will it simply become just another feature to be added on top of Liberty (Liberty Classic?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the presenter on the Virtual POT I can assure you that I did not say that WebSphere 9.x will be the last version of WAS Classic. There is no intention to remove the traditional application server runtime from the WebSphere product. There are far too many people who relying on running it for their business critical applications. I am sorry if I gave that impression.

I did talk about the end of support of WAS v7 and WAS v8 and the need to migrate to WAS v8.5 and v9, and the end of support for Java 6, so perhaps that is where the miscommunication came from.

I'm sorry for causing any confusion in the Virtual POT and I hope my answer puts your mind at rest that WebSphere traditional (or Classic) will be here to stay.

Alasdair